# TypeError: countries.map is not a function in react js ( when i click on on countrie view or edit and then countries link )

Tags: reactjs

TypeError: countries.map is not a function  in react js

( when i click on on countries view or edit and then countries link, i am receiving this error map is not a funtion error, this error is not coming  at a first time.  )

Can some one review this and help me

```
class Countries extends Component
{ 

    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.props.getCountries();

    }


    render()

    {


        const { countries, loading }  = this.props.countries; 

      console.log(countries);


     const country = countries.map(countries => 
                <div key={countries._id}>

                    <table border='1' width ='100%' >
                    <tr><td> {countries.name}</td>
                    <td>{countries.code}        </td>
                    <td>{countries.status}        </td>         
                    <td>  <Link  to={'/countries/'+countries._id} >View</Link></td>
                    <td>  <Link  to={'/countries/edit/'+countries._id} >Edit</Link></td>
                    <td>  <Link  to={'/countries/'+countries._id} >Delete</Link></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>  );  



      return (<div> <h1> Countries list </h1>
        <h3 >You can add new country  from here</h3>
           <p> <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to='/countries/add'>Add</Link></p>
{country}</div>)
    }


}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    countries : state.countries,
    auth : state.auth,
    error : state.errors,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getCountries} )(withRouter(Countries));
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the component is rendered before the `countries` are loaded. You have to check whether the `countries` have been loaded in order to avoid this. This is how to do it:

```
const country = !countries ? [] : countries.map(countries => 
                <div key={countries._id}>

                    <table border='1' width ='100%' >
                    <tr><td> {countries.name}</td>
                    <td>{countries.code}        </td>
                    <td>{countries.status}        </td>         
                    <td>  <Link  to={'/countries/'+countries._id} >View</Link></td>
                    <td>  <Link  to={'/countries/edit/'+countries._id} >Edit</Link></td>
                    <td>  <Link  to={'/countries/'+countries._id} >Delete</Link></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>  );
```

This will give the value of an empty array to `country` if `countries` have not been loaded.